# What does 帰りに寄ってください mean?

Tags: meaning

Can someone tell me the meaning of this phrase 帰りに寄ってください ? I use google translate but it seems to give an answer which is kinda weird. The verb 寄る has a lot of meaning which confuses me.

Comment: Can you share what meanings did you find, which are confusing and in what way?

Comment: Google Translate isn't really a way to learn Japanese.

Comment: Google Translate isn't really a way to translate Japanese either...

Answer (score 4):

寄る means making a stop.

So, it means

> 帰りに寄ってください。
>   Please make a stop on your way home (or somewhere you are going back to).

([reference](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%AF%84%E3%82%8B))